# To prove that a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Actually, I am studying a paper where I didn't understand a line. Can anyone please help me.

Let $\bar f_p(x)=x^p-x^{p-1}-...-x-1$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ where $p$ is prime. Now they are proving that $\bar f_p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

For that, they are claiming that $\bar f_p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ iff

(1) gcd($\bar f_p(x),x^p-x)=1$

(2) $\bar f_p(x)|(x^{p^p}-x)$.

So, I am trying to understand the backward implication. Here if (1) is true then $\bar f_p(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but how the additional condition (2) implies $\bar f_p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

And, also how $\bar f_p(x)$ is irreducible implies (2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We only need that $\overline{f}_p \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is of degree $p$ (prime).

Let $\alpha_i$ be the roots of $\overline{f}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_i) =\mathbb{F}_{p^{n_i}}$. If $\overline{f}_p(x) | x^{p^p}-x$ then for each $i$ : $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}_{p^p}$, thus $n_i = 1$ or $p$. And $gcd(x^p -x , \overline{f}_p) = 1$ means $n_i \ne 1$ ie. $n_i = p$ and $\overline{f}_p$ is irreducible.

Conversely if $\overline{f}_p$ is irreducible then $n_i = p$.

Comment: How you got $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_i) =\mathbb{F}_{p^{n_i}}$? Please break it down for me.

Comment: @Saikat If $g(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible of degree $n$ and $g(\alpha) = 0$ then $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(g(x))\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, and by uniqueness of the finite field with $p^n$ elements (which is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$) we can replace $\cong$ by $=$. Here I applied the same idea to the irreducible factors of $\overline{f}_p$.

Comment: How are you getting $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(g(x))\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and $n_i=1$ or $p$?

Comment: @Saikat Did you read a course about field theory ? Do you know that if $g \in K[x]$ is irreducible then $K[x]/(g(x))$ is irreducible and isomorphic to $K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $g$ ? If $K$ is a finite field with $q$ elements then $K[x]/(g(x))$ has $q^{deg(g)}$ elements. There is only one finite field (up to isomorphism) with $p^n$ elements : the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. What are the subfields of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ ?